# How to add splash screen without window in flutter desktop application

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter desktop application. I want to add splash screen in my application like the one appear when we start android studio, like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGSPq.png).

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5731) with Flutter requesting this documentation.  Please give it a thumbs up to give it more visibility with the Flutter team.

Comment: Thanks alot. Hopefully will get solution.